# two for loop not working properly in dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension

```
recipe = {
    "butter chicken" : "Value",
    "pepper chicken" : "Value",
    "garlic chicken" : "Value",
    "ginger chicken" : "Value",
    }
```

dict comprehension is

```
{key : value for key in range(1, len(recipe)+1) for value in recipe}
```

this is printing

```
{1: 'ginger chicken', 2: 'ginger chicken', 3: 'ginger chicken', 4: 'ginger chicken'}
```

actually i want

```
{1: 'butter chicken', 2: 'pepper chicken', 3: 'garlic chicken', 4: 'ginger chicken'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` for this:

```
listrecipe = dict(enumerate(recipe, 1))
```

Output:

```
{1: 'butter chicken', 2: 'pepper chicken', 3: 'garlic chicken', 4: 'ginger chicken'}
```

If you prefer dict-comprehension with `range`, then it should be:

```
{key: value for key, value in zip(range(1, len(recipe)+1), recipe)}
```

---

#### Why your solution isn't working?

```
listrecipe = {key : value for key in range(1, len(recipe)+1) for value in recipe}
```

is equivalent to:

```
listrecipe = {}

for key in range(1, len(recipe)+1):
    for value in recipe:
        listrecipe[key] = value
```

So for each `key` (from 1 to `len(recipe)+1`) you write each value, so each next value overrides the previous one. That's why only last value is left for every key.

Comment: Thanks its working , but why is this comprehension not working properly

Comment: @vaseemcholakkan I've added some explanation